# Compressed Graph Representation?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, data-structures, graph, compression

I'm working on a side project now that involves encoding all of the links between Wikipedia pages.  I've scraped this information to disk, but the memory usage required to encode the structure of this graph is pretty ridiculous - there's millions of nodes and tens of millions of links.  While this structure does fit in memory, I'm not sure what I'd do if there were, say, a billion links or a billion pages.

My question is - is there a way of losslessly compressing a graph too large to fit into memory so that it does fit in memory?  If not, is there a good lossy algorithm that for some definition of "structure" doesn't lose too much structure from the original graph?

Comment: What representation are you currently using? Matrix-form?

Comment: Simple adjacency list where each page is encoded as a 32-bit integer.

Comment: +1 - a really interesting question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Graphs like links graphs and social graphs are very well studied and they usually have statistical properties that enable efficient compressed representations.

One of these properties, for example, is that for outgoing edges the differential encoding of the adjacency list has a power low distribution, i.e. there are a lot of very small values and very few big values, so most [universal codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_code_(data_compression)) work quite well. In particular the class of [zeta codes](http://vigna.dsi.unimi.it/ftp/papers/WebGraphII.pdf) is provably optimal in this setting, and in the paper the authors compressed the link graph of a small web crawl with about 3 bits per link.

Their code (for Java, Python and C++) is [available in their webpage](http://webgraph.dsi.unimi.it/) as a graph compression framework, so you should be able to experiment with it without much coding.

This algorithm is kind of old (2005) and there have been developments in the field but I don't have the pointers to the papers right now, the improvements are anyway not significant and I don't think there is any available and tested code that implements them.

Answer (score 4):

I was part of [a paper](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/SRC-RR-175.pdf) a while ago about compressing web graphs so they would fit in memory.  We got it down to about 6 bits per link.

Comment: The general problem with applying web graph techniques (and all delta encoding techniques) to Wikipedia is that, on the web, we can reasonably expect that links often connect nodes which are close to each other lexicographically (on the same server or in the same domain). In a dictionary, links are much more random, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/J%C3%B4

Comment: Wikipedia is not that random. I would expect the link graph to have clusters corresponding to the categories, just like the web graph clusters on domains.

Answer (score 3):

Quite generally speaking, if you have N nodes and an average of X outgoing links per node, X much smaller than N, you're going to need XN ln N bits of information to represent this, unless you can find patterns in the link structure (which you can then exploit to bring down the entropy).  XN ln N is within an order of magnitude from the complexity of your 32-bit adjacency list.

There are some tricks you could do to bring down the size some more:

- Use huffman codes to encode link destinations. Assign shorter codes to frequently referenced pages and longer codes to infrequent pages.
- Find a way to break down the set of pages into classes. Store each link between pages within the same class as "0" + "# within class"; links between pages in different categories as "1" + "destination class" + "# within class".

Links from Giuseppe are worth checking, but only the experiment will tell you how well those algorithms are applicable to Wikipedia.

Comment: What do you mean with "XN ln N is within an order of magnitude from the complexity of your 32-bit adjacency list."? The OP asked for algorithm that scale to billions of pages, so `ln N ~= 32`. Also, Huffman codes are not a very good option in this case: you still have to store the table of code lengths which requires at least an additional `N log log N`.

Comment: Exactly. If you have 4 billion pages and links are completely random, you have to spend 32 bits per link. My point is that the trivial adjacency list will work quite well in the situation. N log log N is negligible, considering that X is at least 20, so the code length table adds 5-6 bit per node to the link structure which takes several hundred bit per node.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the sentence as "one order of magnitude better". About huffman, the code table can be expensive for the long tail of nodes with few links (which would also be encoded with long codes, as they probably link to infrequent pages)

Comment: To avoid the hassle of constructing and storing huffman tables, one could sort the list from the most-referenced article to the least-referenced, and then pick an appropriate universal code (at a small penalty to the compression rate).

Answer (score 1):

What about just writing your nodes, links, and associations to an existing scalable database system (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc)?  You can create indexes and stored procedures for faster DB-level processing, if needed.

If you can't go this route for some reason, you'll need to page data in and out (just like DB systems do!).  Compressing the data is a short term band aid in many cases.  If you can't raise the RAM roof for some reason, you're only buying yourself limited time, so I'd recommend against compressing it.

Comment: I definitely have considered this approach.  These are well-established, tried-and-true techniques.  My main question is whether there's some nice information-theoretic machineries or clever data structures that might render this unnecessary.

Comment: Bloom filters are probabilistic, hash-based structures that compress large data sets and are used for things like cache lookups, etc.  But keep in mind that they can emit false positives.  If you can live with that (and many people can), they may work for you.

Comment: BTW, in order to know if Bloom Filters might work for you, we'd have to know more about the operations you're trying to perform on the data.

Comment: a) how is this answering the OPs question? b) a Bloom filter will only tell you if something maybe belongs to a set, you cannot reconstruct the set anymore than you can reconstruct a file just from it's hash...

Comment: We need more info on the operations he wants to perform, but suppose he keeps the nodes in memory and simply wants a probabilistic check for a link between them.  A bloom filter would certainly be useful here.  We need more info on the operations -- I was just suggesting a structure related to the compression of data in memory (which was part of the original question).

Answer (score 1):

If you *do not* need mutability, take a look at how BGL represents a graph in a [compressed sparse row format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/graph/doc/compressed_sparse_row.html). According to the docs it "minimizes memory use to O(n+m) where n and m are the number of vertices and edges, respectively". Boost Graph Library even has [an example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/graph/example/csr-example.cpp) that mirrors your use case.

Before you go to far with this, you should really figure out how you intend to interrogate your graph. Do you need links pointing to the page as well as links out of a page? Do you need to be able to efficiently find the number of links on a given page? For a pretty well thought out list of basic graph operations, take a look at [Boost Graph Library's (BGL) concepts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_concepts.html). You can then map this to requirements for different algorithms. [Dijkstra's shortest path](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html), for example, requires a graph that models "Vertex List Graph" and "Incidence Graph".

Answer (score 1):

in your case you are trying to compress a SINGLE graph into a memory instead a general, large family of graphs. When you have only single graph to compress, you can find any arbitrary algorithmic presentation for it and this becomes an issue of [Kolmogorov complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity). In general, you can't compress random graphs efficiently because they are random and thus can't be predicted and when they can't be predicted they can't be compressed. This comes from basic information theory; it's the same thing that you can't compress images with random noise.

Suppose you have 2<sup>30</sup> (billion) pages and everyone has exactly 2<sup>4</sup> outbound links and that the links are truly randomly distributed. The links on every page represent almost 16 * 30 bits of information (not totally because the 16 links are all distinct and this adds a minuscule amount of redundancy). So you have 2<sup>30</sup> * 16 * 30 = 2<sup>32</sup> * 120 = 15 GB worth of information there, and information theory says you can't find a smaller GENERAL representation. You need to use the particular structure of the Wikipedia graph to get below that information-theoretic lower bound.